# Using Attribute Assistant to update field when value in another layer is updated?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, editing, vbscript, attribute-assistant

I have been searching for an AA method that can update our CP system status field to "UP" in our gas main layer whenever a control point test location is created or modified on that gas main feature. The conditions would be that the control point would have to be created on the gas main, then populated with a control number from the gas main (this is done by the intersecting feature AA method). However, I am unable to find a way to change our CP system status field to "UP" in the gas main layer when said control point is created and populated with a control number.

So, I turned to the expression method in AA to try and accomplish this. I am decent at python expressions but have little experience writing VB expressions (required for this AA method) that could achieve such automation. Does anyone know a good VB expression that could update my CP system status field to "UP" when a control point is created and attributes modified? This would most likely be a conditional statement.

Comment: What format is the data stored in? Shapefile, File Geodatabase, Enterprise Database? This will help people when writing a response.

Comment: [Intersecting feature trigger](http://solutions.arcgis.com/shared/help/attribute-assistant/documentation/methods-intersecting-features/#trigger-attribute-assistant-event-intersecting-feature) should handle this.

Comment: I am testing these AA methods on a file geodatabase copy of our gas mains and CP test locations. I will definitely give Intersecting Feature Trigger a try, as I have not considered that AA method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While researching the intersect feature trigger AA method, I stumbled upon the solution to my own problem. The method I needed here is [Update Intersecting Feature](http://solutions.arcgis.com/shared/help/attribute-assistant/documentation/methods-all-methods/#update-intersecting-feature). This method monitors the CP test location layer for changes and allows a target field within a target layer to be updated with either a field name OR a value. In the source field parameter, I simply inputted the value "UP" to be added to the target field. I tested this by placing a new test location on an intersecting gas main and it updated the field perfectly.